# Don't display if no user input is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where I am displaying an amount to the user. Unfortunately I have noticed that if the user inputs no data, it will just display a "%", which looks kinda awkward. I want to not display anything if the user does not input anything. Here's the code I have so far:

```
%tbody
  - @payer_contracts.each do |payer_contract|
    %tr
      %td= payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage.to_s + '%'
```

I am wanting to make it so that it does not display the "%". I tried this, but this is not working:

```
%tbody
  - @payer_contracts.each do |payer_contract|
    %tr
      if payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage != nil?
        %td= payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage.to_s + '%'
```

Any ideas?

This is html.haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
%td= "#{payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage}%" if payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage.present?
```

Only show the content if there is content.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage` is an empty string which is != to nil in ruby.  Try using `present?` like this:

```
%tbody
  - @payer_contracts.each do |payer_contract|
    %tr
      if payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage.present?
        %td= payer_contract.stoploss_reimbursement_percentage.to_s + '%'
```